# Issue resizing Map widget within WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, dictionary

I have a simple Map within a Grid that fills one of its rows.
When the user taps on the Map I want it to fill the entire screen size (possibly with an animation).

This is the Grid with the Map widget:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid x:Name="stackPanel">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Maps:Map x:Name="storesMap" Grid.Row="0" Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}" ScaleVisibility="Visible" CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Visible" Visibility="Collapsed" Tap="storesMap_Tap" VerticalAlignment="Top" ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed" Margin="9,0,12,12" CredentialsProvider="AgKbZTg6fSdp1j_edOa7hCUc6mUoj6duKABt8hMu_PHEG7JjaAJBWqkdODjctYDG">
            <Maps:Map.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Maps:Map.RenderTransform>
            <Maps:MapLayer x:Name="myPushpinLayer">
                <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="storePin" ItemsSource="{Binding StoresPinList}" />
            </Maps:MapLayer>
        </Maps:Map>

        <StackPanel x:Name="WaitingControls" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,24,0,0">

      .....
```

and this is the animation (part of it) that re-sizes the Map and dims PageTitle and ApplicationTitle to 0.

```
         <VisualState x:Name="FullscreenMap">
            <Storyboard Duration="00:00:0.3">
                <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="00:00:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PageTitle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="00:00:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ApplicationTitle" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation From="188" To="800" Duration="00:00:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Storyboard.TargetName="storesMap"/>
                <DoubleAnimation From="435" To="480" Duration="00:00:0.3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Storyboard.TargetName="storesMap"/>
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" Duration="00:00:0.3" To="-161" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="storesMap" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" Duration="00:00:0.3" To="-21" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="storesMap" d:IsOptimized="True"/>

             .....
```

Issue is that the Map DOES re-sizes nicely to fill the screen (and it's 0,0 moves to the top right corner), BUT I can't drag it (the actual map) around!!!
I can only drag it if I start the drag in an area at the top of the screen whose size matches the original size (before the animation). It's like there's a kind of view (the one responsible for receiving the touch/drag events) that didn't re-size along the whole map.

Even the pushpin layer that's on top of it gets "cut". If a pin goes outside the original viewable size at the top, it gets cut (as if going outside of the screen), even if the map still show normally all the way down to the bottom of the screen.

Any idea why??

Aniello